# CrashLytics prints some log message after initializing and crash logs are emailed

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

When i try initialize CrashLytics i get Log message.

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.0.9 (54)
[Crashlytics:Crash] Reporting is disabled
[Crashlytics] Crash reporting could not be initialized..


[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit, TwitterKit]];
```

I also tried

```
[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"my long key"];
```

Any idea guys whats is happening..I ve my crashlytics and Twitter fully updated.

Answer (score 1):

Being faced with the same issue some time ago I finally found a solution. Make sure that you have specified correct API key as shown in screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: I have API key setup but still got the same issue.